# How to generate Random number of 12 bytes?

Tags: c, linux

I'm working on project on linux in C and in which i need to generate random number of 12 bytes.
I have searched over internet but i couldn't find any other than srand or random function. 
But these functions can only generate random number of 32-bit(4 byte).

I'm looking for generating random number of 12 byte.

Does anybody know anything library on linux which provide this functionality ?

Comment: which method did you use for the 4 byte number

Comment: If I have my math right, 12 = 3*4

Comment: "Does anybody know anything library on linux which provide this functionality?" - Sure, the standard library.

Comment: What is a number of 12 bytes to you? *C* has no such type natively... So fill your data with more or less random bytes. And you did not tell how random you want that data to be.

Comment: Hi all, sorry for late reply but due to health issue, I couldn't work after posted question. Btw, thanks all for replying. This is my first question on stackoverflow. :)
@Nemo: Yes, I was also thinking to generate 3 random numbers and fill my 12 byte buffer
@ H2CO3: I was asking about routine functionality in standard library. 
@ Basile : yes, you are right. I want random number everytime as it is supposed to be used to track the packet request/reply between server/client.

Answer (score 6):

OK so finally a **solution:**

```
unsigned char buf[12];
int i;
srand(time(NULL));
for (i = 0; i < sizeof(buf); i++) {
    buf[i] = rand() % 256;
}
```

(Yes, I'm using modulo - if you care about uniform distribution, don't use it.)

Comment: thanks for providing suggestion. I need to check whether this can fit to my requirement as i have to use all 12 bytes of random number as unique number to track packets between server/client.

Comment: @SujalSheth Perhaps if you specified your **requirement...** so this is a so-called "XY problem". Then why don't you simply use libuuid?

Comment: I can't use each byte generated using rand() call as it will be performance impact.

Comment: @SujalSheth Then choose a language that natively supports 12-byte integers. C does not. (Btw, this ***is*** premature optimization.)

Comment: You are using srand for the seeding but rand to generate the random numbers. Therefore, the seeding will have no effect on the generation of the random numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You did not tell what 12 random bytes mean to you, and why you need them.

You should read [random(4)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man4/random.4.html) then perhaps code

```
unsigned char myrandbytes[12];
FILE* fr = fopen("/dev/urandom", "r");
if (!fr) perror("urandom"), exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
fread(myrandbytes, sizeof(char), 12, fr);
fclose(fr), fr = NULL;
```

But very often, using `rand(3)` as suggested in [that answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14744770/841108) should be enough. You could also use [random(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/random.3.html) or [lrand48(3)](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/lrand48.3.html). I am usually happy enough with `random(3)` which I usually seed -e.g. with `srandom` or `initstate` by reading `/dev/urandom` at start time.

Since you did not tell us why you need random numbers, we cannot help more.

If the quality of the random number is very important (e.g. for strong cryptographic purposes), it might be much more hard than you think, and it is system and hardware dependent (read again the `random(4)` page).

Comment: i need to use this random number for keeping track of packets between server/client. This random number must be unique so every packet can be traced out separately.

Comment: to be more precisely and concise , Client generate this nonce (unique 12 byte number) for it's identity and sends with request packet to server. Server uses this number to identify which client it's talking with. Later this number used by server notify client with several updates.